# How to solve an error in R if else statement inside the for-loop

Tags: r, if-statement

I am creating a model using multiple if else conditions in R.
However, I am kept getting a syntax error message.
My code is below:

```
code <- "model{ 
    for (i in 1:length(N)) {
    n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
    if(age[i] < 20) {
    seropos_est[i] <- 1-exp(-lambda_1*age[i])
    } else {
   seropos_est[i]  <- 1-((exp(-lambda_1*20))*(exp((-lambda_2*(age[i]-20)))))
    }
    }
  #  prior dists
  lambda_1 ~ dunif(0,1) #uninformative prior
    }"
```

I got an error

```
 syntax error on line 4 near "<"
```

Comment: Is `jcode` intended to be a string?

Comment: yes, it's a model that will be put into a jags.model function.

Comment: i got a syntax error: syntax error on line 5 near "&"

Comment: Your last two `1-exp(etc` have a close parenthesis too much. I have edited, i think it's OK now.